# Is there a way to fix this "Trying to get property 'taxonomy' of non-object" error on my Wordpress/Woocommerce site?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a new Wordpress/Woocommerce website using the Avada theme. The site is not live yet.

The store has custom product taxonomies, and as some of the taxonomy names contain a comma I've had to find a code snippet to do a workaround in PHP so that the comma is displayed without splitting the taxonomy name into two separate names (eg. Bouncy Balls, Putty and Slime). The PHP I found has replaced a double dash (--) with a comma in the front end, which appears to work as it should.

My problem is, that since I have added this code I'm getting an error at the top of the page on individual product pages:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'taxonomy' of non-object in /var/sites/a/mywebsite.com/public_html/wpnew/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 32

Line 32 code:

```
if( $tag_arr->taxonomy == 'post_tag' && strpos( $tag_arr->name, '--' ) ) {
```

All of the code I inserted into functions.php is below.

I'm not sure what to try to fix this as this is all new to me and I'm learning as I go along. I have very little knowledge of PHP, besides the snippet I have found online and placed here.

```
if( !is_admin() ){
    function comma_tag_filter( $tag_arr ){
        $tag_arr_new = $tag_arr;
        if( $tag_arr->taxonomy == 'post_tag' && strpos( $tag_arr->name, '--' ) ) {
            $tag_arr_new->name = str_replace( '--', ', ', $tag_arr->name );
        }
        return $tag_arr_new;    
    }
    add_filter( 'get_post_tag', 'comma_tag_filter' );

    function comma_tags_filter( $tags_arr ) {
        $tags_arr_new = array();
        foreach( $tags_arr as $tag_arr ) {
            $tags_arr_new[] = comma_tag_filter( $tag_arr );
        }
        return $tags_arr_new;
    }
    add_filter( 'get_terms', 'comma_tags_filter' );
    add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'comma_tags_filter' );
}
```

I expected this code to work without errors, but I have the error message at the top of the product pages.

Thanks for any help

Comment: if( $tag_arr['taxonomy'] == 'post_tag' && strpos( $tag_arr['name'], '--' ) ) {

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the following error on the front end, along with more line 32 errors:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array in /var/sites/a/arktoys.com/public_html/wpnew/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php:32

Comment: Unfortunately after much searching there doesn't seem to be a way to fix the problem with this code without it causing errors in the front end.